# New "Questions with new activity" banner seems buggy

Tags: bug, android-app

(It's not showing up now. Were you guys testing something on your end?)

For the first time today, I saw a blue banner across the top of the question feed that said "2 questions with new activity" (paraphrasing, can't remember the exact wording). To the right of it was a refresh button (two circular arrows pointing at each other).

Clicking the refresh button seems to do nothing though. It didn't cause any noticeable changes to the feed, or give any feedback that it had even registered the press (like making the refresh button look pressed). Nothing new was loaded, or changed.

The banner also only seems to show up on Meta feeds. I have yet to see it happen in the SO question feed.

And yes, this was **definitely** in the app. I only ever use the Android app.

App version 1.0.95

Android 6.0.1; rooted.

Comment: can you add a screenshot (still or gif)?

Comment: @OptimusPrime I'll try to get one. Ofc, now it's not showing up at all.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such thing in the app. You probably viewed the site in browser.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope. Was the app. I never use the actual site on my phone. I exclusively use the app unless I need to check something like whether or not a flag was approved.

Comment: Now it's not showing up. They must have been testing something on their end.

Comment: By "question feed", do you mean the the screen with a list of questions that is shown after you choose a site (where you can also search and change sort order)?

Comment: @Success Yes. That screen.